# An everywhere locally trivial line bundle

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Is there a variety $X$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and a line bundle $L$ over $X$ (other than the trivial line bundle $\mathcal{O}_X$ ) such that $L_v$ is the trivial line bundle over $X_v=X\times_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{Q}_v$ for every place $v$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

(Answer known.  There is a pun on "locally trivial" in the title.)

Comment: Forgive me for asking, but if the answer is known, could you show it to us? 

Comment: I thought people would like to think about it.  

Comment: The moral of this one seems to me "don't let on that you know the answer" :-/ Maybe it's time you answered your own question?

Comment: Sorry for having kept everyone waiting !  I had to be away three days...

Comment: Others may disagree, but I think it's against the spirit of things here to ask a question to which you already know the answer (however nice the question is).  It might seem like an abuse of people's willingness to help.  

Comment: I did say "Answer known".  I'm willing to delete the question if a majority would like me to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following example was provided to me by Colliot-Thélène some years ago :  Let $X$ be the complement in $\mathbb{P}_{1,\mathbb{Q}}$ of the three closed points defined by $x^2=13$, $x^2=17$, $x^2=221$.  Then $\operatorname{Pic}(X)=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ but $\operatorname{Pic}(X_v)=0$ for every place $v$ of $\mathbb{Q}$.